# FontWeight not work with Chinese in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Below is my test code:

```dart
Text(
  'I love 中国',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
),
Text(
  'I love 中国',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
),
```

Result:

[image]

You can see with different fontWeight letter works but Chinese act the same.

How can I solve it?

*My flutter is 3.3.2.*

**Note: run on iOS.**

Answer (score 2):

Flutter will search for a font on the host system that is closest to the specified font weight. But if the system only provides one font that handles the requested characters, then Flutter and Skia will synthesize a "fake bold" version of that font to handle other font weights.

Due to [issue on github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47861)

Comment: BTW, I think you need to find a fontFamily which support

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1: Set `theme` in your `MaterialApp`:

```dart
theme: ThemeData(
  fontFamily: "PingFang SC",
),
```

#### Solution 2: Set `fontFamilyFallback` where you need:

```dart
Text(
  'I love 中国',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
    color: Colors.red,
    fontFamilyFallback: ["PingFang SC", "Heiti SC"],
  ),
),
```

#### Solution 3: Use `DefaultTextStyle` with `fontFamilyFallback`:

```dart
DefaultTextStyle(
  style: TextStyle(
    fontFamilyFallback: ["PingFang SC", "Heiti SC"],
    color: Colors.red,
    fontSize: 30,
  ),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text(
        'I love 中国',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        ),
      ),
      Text(
        'I love 中国',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
        ),
      ),
      Text(
        'I love 中国',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image]